# not able to get user input in javascript from html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know that I should use `document.getelemtbyID` but for some reason it has not worked for me. I am trying to build a simple rock paper scissor game where I have a rock paper scissor class and one `index.js`, I have to pass the username as a function to my class but I am unable to get it working.
Here is my Javascript code -

```js
const userName = document.getElementById(`username`).value;
```

and then i pass it to the class -

```
let game=new RockPaperScissors(userName)
game.play(userName); (which is a function in the class)
```

Here is my HTML for taking in username -

```
  <div id="welcome-screen">
           <form id="name-form">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="username">Your name</label>
                   <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control"
                          name="username" placeholder="Enter Name Here...">
                   <button type="button" id="start-game-button"
                           class="btn btn-primary">Start Game!</button>

               </div>
           </form>
```

I tried several ways to be able to log in the username in my javascript but it's not working, I tried logging it in console and i still don't see a result.

Comment: Can you post the method that is invoked when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

About your above code : there is no pre-defined method of click event in the core javascript, so i have created one function in javascript and just called it on button onclick event.

your code is just got value of the textbox, but there is no event triggered, to get the value of textbox.

```js
var name = "";
function getname() {
  name = document.getElementById(`username`).value;
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome-screen">
    <form id="name-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Your name</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Enter Name Here...">
        <button type="button" onclick="getname()" id="start-game-button" class="btn btn-primary">Start Game!</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: or visit this : https://codepen.io/parth-mehta-the-vuer/pen/BaoXyjr

Comment: @StephenP  i have added some explanation into it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you help me a little more by telling me how i could probably make that name variable global in my javascript because i need to pass it to call more objects ! I tried adding " return name" at end of the function but it did not seem to work :(

Comment: @rishabh111 check the answer now i have declare it outside of the function, now you can use it anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type=submit` to the button.

```
<button type="submit" id="start-game-button" class="btn btn-primary">Start Game!</button>
```